# Prevent action attribute from running php script with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way that I can use javascript to prevent a form from runing a php script. For example something like this:

```
<form action="somePage.php" method="POST>

<input type= "text" class= "field"  name = "blah">

<input type="submit" value="Send" >

</form>
```

I know how to validate what's in that text box using javascript, but I want to prevent the somePage.php to run if the text box is empty. I haven't really tried anything cause I just don't know how to do it.

Hope you guys understand my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach function to `submit` event of the `form`:

```
document.getElementById('form-id').addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    var field1 = getElementById('field1').value;
    if(field1=='' || field1 == null){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Pls fill the required fields.');
      return;
    }
    return true;
});
```

***OR***

*Below solution uses inline js:*

If you want to run your js function before submitting the form to php script, you can use `onsubmit` attribute of the form,

```
<form id="form-id" action="somePage.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return formSubmit();">

  <input type= "text" class= "field" id="field1"  name = "blah">

  <input type="submit" value="Send" >

</form>
```

In `formSubmit` function you can check the value of the input, if its empty or not, and if empty, then you can just `return false;`

```
    var formSubmit = function(){
        var field1 = getElementById('field1').value;
        if(field1=='' || field1 == null)
          return false;
        else
          return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'd upvote, but I can't since you're advocating inline javascript.

Comment: huh? I don't follow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks @Rao check this out for formatting. avoid using inline event listeners.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I don't put in in script tag, SO wont know which language the code is in. and wouldn't color code it properly.

Comment: @Rao `onsubmit=return function()` <-- that's inline js. Code between script tags is external, and not what I was referencing

Comment: Could you pls suggest an edit to my answer? How do I avoid inline js ? I shouldn;t use onsubmit="" is it ?

Comment: @Rao Add an event listener to the event type `submit` check below answers.

Comment: Updated my answer with event listeners, so you don't have to write any inline js, which is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to `return false` for your submit event by grabbing the form (I used `querySelector` because you have no IDs or classes), and adding a submit listening event to return false.

```
var x = document.querySelector("[method='POST']");
x.addEventListener("submit",function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: seems like it could work. I'll give a try

Comment: Have you even tested this code? Not working here.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to prevent form from submitting:

```
var first_form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

first_form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();      //This actually prevent browser default behaviour
    alert('Don\'t submit');
    //Do your stuff here
}, false);
```

Better read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

Answer (score -2):

you could in your somePage.php have this be a clause somewhere new the beggin:

```
if(empty($_POST['blah'])){
  die();
}
```

or the inverse of

```
if(!empty($_POST['blah'])){
  //do what this php is supposed to
}
else{
  //display error
}
```

this will prevent your php from running if that field is not filled out.

Personally I return them to the same page setting some error on the page.

Comment: The question was how to prevent the PHP script with javascript, please read more carefully

Comment: How this prevent form from submitting?

Comment: it's ok, thanks for the advise. Code is always acceptable in my book, even if it's not what I asked. It might help in a different situation.